# azure node js functions app binding type(s) 'sql' were not found

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a node js functions app in which i am trying to use sql binding and load data from a table.

When i added Sql binding i got following error

The function is in error: The binding type(s) 'sql' were not found in the configured extension bundle. Please ensure the type is correct and the correct version of extension bundle is configured

my host.json file

```
{


"version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Following is my functions.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name":"myMetaSql",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "in",
      "commandText":"SELECT [REGNNO],[My_LOAD_DATE] FROM [vms].[tabS_Meta]",
      "commandType":"Text",
      "connectionStringSettings":"SqlConnectionString_SETTING"

    }
  ]
}
```

Following is my functions file

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, myMetaSql) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        mimetype: "application/json",
        body: myMetaSql
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***I got the same error when I tried to reproduce with your code:***

[image]

Then I changed ***extension bundle*** version to `[4.*, 5.0.0)` and tried with below code, it worked.

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
      }
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
    }
  }
}
```

**function.json:**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "sql",
      "name": "results",
      "direction": "in",
      "commandText": "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MetaDatatable]",
      "commandType": "Text",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "SqlConnectionString":"<your_sql_db_connection_string"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req, results) {
    context.log('Query results: ', JSON.stringify(results));
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: results
    };
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]